# Cannot start embeded Apache Felix

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I want to create Java Desktop application based on Apache Felix Framework. I created this main Java Class:

```
package test.main;

import test.activator.Activator;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory;

/**
 * This class provides a static {@code main()} method so that the bundle can be
 * run as a stand-alone host application. In such a scenario, the application
 * creates its own embedded OSGi framework instance and interacts with the
 * internal extensions to providing drawing functionality. To successfully
 * launch the stand-alone application, it must be run from this bundle's
 * installation directory using "{@code java -jar}". The locations of any
 * additional extensions that have to be started, have to be passed as command
 * line arguments to this method.
 */
public class StartApplication
{

    private static Framework m_framework = null;
    public static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    /**
     * Enables the bundle to run as a stand-alone application. When this static
     * {@code main()} method is invoked, the application creates its own
     * embedded OSGi framework instance and interacts with the internal
     * extensions to provide drawing functionality. To successfully launch as a
     * stand-alone application, this method should be invoked from the bundle's
     * installation directory using "{@code java -jar}". The location of any
     * extension that shall be installed can be passed as parameters.
     * <p>
     * For example if you build the bundles inside your workspace, maven will
     * create a target directory in every project. To start the application from
     * within your IDE you should pass:
     * <p>
     *
     * <pre>
     * {@code file:../servicebased.circle/target/servicebased.circle-1.0.0.jar
     * file:../servicebased.square/target/servicebased.square-1.0.0.jar
     * file:../servicebased.triangle/target/servicebased.triangle-1.0.0.jar}
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param args The locations of additional bundles to start.
     *
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        map.put(1, "/opt/bundle1.jar");
//        map.put(2, "test value 2");
//        map.put(3, "test value 3");

        // Args should never be null if the application is run from the command
        // line.
        // Check it anyway.
        //String[] locations = args != null ? args : new String[0];

        // Print welcome banner.
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to My Launcher");
        System.out.println("======================\n");

        try
        {
            Map<String, String> config = ConfigUtil.createConfig();
            m_framework = createFramework(config);
            m_framework.init();
            m_framework.start();
            installAndStartBundles();
            m_framework.waitForStop(0);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not create framework: " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Util method for creating an embedded Framework. Tries to create a
     * {@link FrameworkFactory} which is then be used to create the framework.
     *
     * @param config the configuration to create the framework with
     * @return a Framework with the given configuration
     */
    private static Framework createFramework(Map<String, String> config)
    {
        ServiceLoader<FrameworkFactory> factoryLoader = ServiceLoader
                .load(FrameworkFactory.class);
        for (FrameworkFactory factory : factoryLoader)
        {
            return factory.newFramework(config);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Unable to load FrameworkFactory service.");
    }

    /**
     * Installs and starts all bundles used by the application. Therefore the
     * host bundle will be started. The locations of extensions for the host
     * bundle can be passed in as parameters.
     *
     * @param bundleLocations the locations where extension for the host bundle
     * are located. Must not be {@code null}!
     * @throws BundleException if something went wrong while installing or
     * starting the bundles.
     */
    private static void installAndStartBundles() throws BundleException, Exception
    {
        BundleContext bundleContext = m_framework.getBundleContext();
        Activator hostActivator = new Activator();
        hostActivator.start(bundleContext);

        for (String location : map.values())
        {
            Bundle addition = bundleContext.installBundle(location);
            addition.start();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the jar file I get this error:

```
[rcbandit@Laptop target]$ java -jar ./DX-57-1.0.jar

Welcome to My Launcher
======================

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/launch/FrameworkFactory
    at dx57.main.StartApplication.createFramework(StartApplication.java:95)
    at dx57.main.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 2 more
```

Can you tell me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you start on such a low level if you're clearly not experienced with OSGi? At your current level you should follow one of the many tutorials or use bndtools to get started and then later move to launchers etc. since they are quite low level and require understanding the whole model.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have an OSGi Framework on the application classpath, e.g. Felix. For example you should launch as follows:

```
java -cp DX-57-1.0.jar;org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar test.main.StartApplication
```

Comment: Not easily. You would have to copy the full package structure of the Felix framework JAR into your own JAR, because the java launcher does not support nested JARs on the classpath.